# Gluster remove-brick from volume failed, what to do to remove a brick?

Tags: glusterfs

I had a gluster volume named `data` of distributed mode. I added a brick `server1:/vdata/bricks/data` to the volume `data`, However I found that `vdata/bricks/data` is on the `/` disk of linux. I wanna remove the brick from volume. So I use `gluster volume remove disk data server1:/vdata/bricks/data start`. Then I check the status using `gluster volume remove-brick data server1:/vdata/bricks/data status` but found the status is failed, and the scanned files is always 0. So what could I do to remove this brick without lossing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason myself. It is because of DNS resolution failure for some server nodes. After I recovered the DNS, everything works OK!